# how do I fix the System.BadImageFormat exception?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-4.0, asp.net-3.5

I am having a visual studio 2010 window service application in .net framework version 3.5 but I need to use a dll in my service which was built in .net framework version 4.0.So I have upgraded my version to 4.0 but while installing my service i am having system.BadImageFormatException.How to fix this.Please suggest some solution.

This is the error message I am getting

Error 1001.Exception occurred while initializing the installation: System.BadImageFormatExceptio: could not load file or assembly 'file://C:.....exe' or more or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Thanks in advance

Comment: 13 questions asked and not a single upvote, accepted answer or answered question. Why don't you take a read of the FAQ (linked at the top of the page) and consider reciprocating some of the help you have already been given?

Answer (score 1):

The application and the DLL (including all dependencies of each) must all be either 32-bit or 64-bit. Most likely, the binaries you are using are not. To fix the problem build or otherwise obtain access to the correct binaries.

If this is not the problem, the "remarks" section of the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception.aspx) lists all the reasons that can cause this exception to be thrown, including solutions for each.